# Centering a dynamic and fixed div

Tags: jquery, css

I am not good in css and I already spent so many hours doing this, I want to center a fixed / dynamic size div. Its like

```
<div>
    // Imagine to have a multiple images here, size is 100x100. 
    // When I click on the image (I am using jquery for this), #fade will appear and a window 
    // that contain the original size of the image.
    <img class="picture" src="picture.jpg" width="100" height=100"/>
</div>
<div id="fade"></div>
<div class="imgWindow">
    <img src="picture.jpg"/> // original size
</div>
```

css

```
#fade {
    display: none;
    background: black;
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

.imgWindow {
    width: 640px;
    height: 422px;
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    z-index: 11;
    left: 0; top: 0;
}
```

The image window should be centered even if I re-size the browser window.
Please help, thanks!

Comment: does the new image opens in a new window or the same window

Comment: In the same window, something like a modal window.

Answer (score 0):

i would rather go jquery..this jquery function will always center the image

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
        this.css("position","absolute");
        this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
        this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the CSS property "`position`", you can't center the element except by tweaking the other properties that you use. You should use those in pairs:

try

```
img{
width: XXpx;
height: YYpx;
position: fixed;
top: YY%;
left: XX%;
border: 0;
z-index: 1; /* optional */
}
```

http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/de…